# Password Life Cycle for Machine to Machine

Tags: security, passwords, password-encryption

Wanted to see if there exists a mechanism to achieve the following:

Server `S` running version `A`; Client `C` running version `A`

Clients communicate with the server using REST over TLS.

Now after some months, the admin changes the REST password on the Server. How do we update the password on Client?

Comment: This is probably more of a Server Fault question than a Stack Overflow question, but I'll take a crack. OK, so, you might want to ask yourself why there's this 1 REST password. Why don't your user accounts have their own authentication which is unaffected by your upgrades to the REST API and which also has a password reset feature in case it's needed? Also, why would an upgrade break your REST API? I'm using Jersey and Swagger for my REST API and while the package gets periodically upgraded and therefor my other server-side software also needs to get upgraded, there's no update to the REST API

Comment: that would break queries. The clients' queries written 5 - 7 years ago would still work today, so why would this be a problem for the client? Also aren't you storing password hashes in a DB? So why would a change to the REST API library affect the contents of the database (i.e. the hashes)?

Comment: @Hack-R, It is machine-to-machine. So there are no separate user-accounts. It is this password-reset behavior that I'm trying to achieve. For the 2nd part, you are right. Let me edit the question to remove the 2nd part.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can read, your question basically boils down to the following:

*When some client system `C` depends on access to a server system `S`, and the password for `S` is changed, how can `C` easily be informed about it, and recieve the new password?*

The answer of course, is "It depends", or perhaps "however you want". If there is some third party system that both `C` and ´S´ can access in a secure way, then perhaps both of them could fetch the password from there on a regular basis, but then you've got the issue of securing access to *that* service.

Does `S`have to be publicly facing? If possible, a better solution might be to run the whole call from `C` to `S` via a VPN (or some other conceptually similar solution?). That way you could "wrap" the whole process into a secure connection which could perhaps(?) eliminate the need for a password entirely.